# Recorder.js save to server results in corrupt mp3

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I've read over countless related topics but still need some help  I'm using this Github script https://github.com/Audior/Recordmp3js

Everything is working, file is being saved on the server,  the resulting mp3 blog: url sounds as it should, but the copy that is uploaded to the server through the upload.php file is just a short pink noise sound, it's either corrupt or the wrong format.

Could someone take a look at the 2 screenshots and guide me in the right direction. I suspect it has something to do with incorrect amount of channels and/or buffer rate.

The first screenshot is correct result which is from the demo, both the blog: url plays fine and the uploaded copy also sounds and the log looks as expected

The 2nd screenshot is of the problem one, as with the first the blog: url sounds fine but when I upload it this is the result .. .mp3 file is correct size when it is uploaded but is just a short static sound

[image: Here is the correct result which is from the demo, both the blog: url plays fine and the uploaded copy also sounds and the log looks as expected]

[image: The 2nd screenshot is of the problem one, as with the first the blog: url sounds fine but when I upload it this is the result .. .mp3 file is correct size when it is uploaded but is just a short static sound]

Comment: A code sample would be nice. The encoding/data type is your problem. It probably needs to be something like an array buffer, but yours is just putting it out to a string.

Comment: @user3228114 you have shown no indication of things that you have tried in order to solve the problem. Based on your question you ran into an issue, did not try to solve it, then posted the problem on stackoverflow. That is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Also @user3228114 people are volunteering their time to answer questions on this forum. You will learn quick to show respect on here or you will not get help from anyone.

Comment: I provided a URL to the code I was using it's the recorder.js file.

Comment: I provided 2 screenshots and the entire URL for the recorder.js file, what more did you need? If you are not able to answer a question, the don't anwser

Comment: Since nobody is able to see the URL for the code at the very top, Ill post it again

Answer (score -1):

Everyone complained about how my question was formed rather then try to help, all but one ... forget it!